# How to disable cookies for anonymous Users in Drupal 7

Tags: session, cookies, drupal-7

I would like to disable cookies set by Drupal 7 for anonymous users.

I found a solutions for settings.php

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0');
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', '0');
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', '1');
```

But this will prevent me from logging in as an administrator.

So, does somebody know how to disable cookies *only* for anonymous users?

Comment: What is the main reason to disable cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 doesn't set session cookies for anonymous users (at least newer versions), so that's one pain less here.

If you want to remove has_js cookie for anonymous user, you might solve it by adding a piece of code loading additional JS file in your theme and expiring the cookie there.

Loading JS file in your theme:

```
function yourtheme_process_page(&$variables) {
    [...code...]
    global $user;
    if ( !$user->uid) {
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'yourtheme') . '/js/remove_has_js.js');
    }
}
```

Contents of JS file (setting cookie for sometime in the past will expire/delete it):

```
document.cookie = 'has_js=0; expires=Fri, 01 Jan 1977 01:00:00 GMT; path=/';
```